# How to configure IntelliJ to resolve ~ in JavaScript programs

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm working on an existing codebase where the JavaScript imports are written like this:

`import { somethingToImport } from '~/dir1/dir2/fileName'`

Which resolves (via webpack) to

`${project_root}/src/dir1/dir2/fileName`

I know that it's more standard to use relative path imports in JavaScript, but I can't change the entire codebase. So I'm wondering how to configure IntelliJ (or WebStorm) to resolve the import - letting me click through and "find usages" normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack-specific modules resolving (`resolve.moduleDirectories`, `resolve.root`, `resolve.alias`, etc.) is not currently supported. Please follow [WEB-13409](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13409) and linked tickets for updates