# WebStorm. When I define scss in a .vue,the "@import 'xxx'" display error

Tags: settings, webstorm

demo.vue:

```
<template>
  ...
</template>
<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
  ...
</script>
<style lang="scss" rel="stylesheet/scss">
    @import "~scss/variables.scss";
    .pop-up-box {
      ...
    }
</style>
```

Everything is fine: coding, compiling, working.

Just WebStorm will display error at

```
@import "~scss/variables.scss";
```

Because of WebStorm want to check the path of `~scss/variables.scss` but this path is a webpack alias.
It will show `Cannot resolve directory '~scss'`.

Is there any way to let WebStorm know here is a webpack alias or just not show error any more?

Comment: AFAIK -- not at the moment. Have a look at this answer from JetBrains team member: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42116001/783119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way currently, please follow [WEB-25321](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25321) for updates. WebStorm provides no support for Webpack-specific modules resolving (`resolve.moduleDirectories`, `resolve.root`, `resolve.alias`, etc.). 
Note that basic support is provided for stylesheet languages (LESS, SCSS), so  that webpack-specific imports like "@import '~webpackPackage/test.css'" don't cause errors if `~` is equal to  `node_modules` directory. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23707#comment=27-1657238

Comment: That issue is marked as "fixed", but it still doesn't work, even with new projects created via `vue-cli@3`.

Comment: please make sure to specify a path to `node_modules\@vue\cli-service\webpack.config.js` in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack**

Comment: Did that. Still not working with `IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)` `Build #IU-192.6262.58` on `LinuxMint`.

Comment: what does your import look like? `@import "~@/styles/variables"` where `styles` is `<project root>/src/styles` works fine for me

Comment: The import looks like `@import '@/scss/variables';` and lives inside the `<style lang="scss" scoped>` tag in a `.vue` file. The file `<project root>/src/scss/_variables.scss` exists.

Comment: try prepending `@` with `~` - see https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#resolving-import-at-rules, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717203/webpack-with-sass-loader-scss-file-import-does-not-recognize-resolve-alias

Comment: The problem is not with webpack. It builds. The problem is with IDEA not finding the imports. Just like in the OP's question. Also, the problem is only inside <style lang="scss"> blocks.

Comment: I have them same issue in sass files using @import. Intellij IDEA 2019.2.4